# CSS align 2 HTML forms

Tags: html, forms, css

I've tried many ways, but can't achieve what I need in any way.

So I have this for now:

[image: wrong forms align]

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: correct form align]

There is div `#Container` which holds 2 forms: `#Form1` and `#Form2`. `#Form1` is for customizing profile picture and `#Form2` is for user's personal details like name, email, website, etc.

I wanna achieve that profile picture would be aligned on the left side, in right side should go text fields for the first name, last name, email and when the bottom of form1 is reached, form2 should start to align left as shown in the image.

If for example `#Form1` I set to 30% and `Form2` to 60% width it looks like this:

[image: wrong forms align2]

Any ideas how could I achieve It, I've tried to make `#Form1` relative, `#Form2` absolute, but incorrect result too.

This is sample css for now:

```
#Form1 {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#Form2 {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

HTML sample:

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="form1">
    <!-- Content of Form1 -->
    </form> 
    <form id="form2">
    <!-- Content of Form2 -->
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add a width to your Form1 only and float it left. The other will just float naturally around it providing form2 has no container

Comment: Essentially, though, all HTML objects are **rectangular**. you might need to re-think your structure.

Comment: @Paulie_D hmm, I need to make that `Form1` go around `Form2` maybe you missed something, I believe it's possible.

Comment: @Infinity Yeah...I get that...and  you **can't**.

Comment: As @Amy said, you could put Form 1 **inside** Form 2 and float it left...that might work but we don't know how your existing HMTL actually looks.

Comment: @Paulie_D looks like it's possible, Wouter's answer is proving that. Thank you, guys.

Comment: No...it really doesn't. It just breaks up the existing form into two **rectangles** like I said.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mvbe0rbh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making form1 positioned absolute and deviding form2 in multiple divs (still in one parent form though), like here: https://jsfiddle.net/v6g1h14d/1/

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#Form1 {
  padding: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
#Form2 {
    width: 60%;
    height: 300px;
}

form {
  display: inline;
}

#Form2 .top {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
}

#Form2 .bottom {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="Form1">
    <form>
     form 1
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Form2">
    <form>
      <div class="top">content of form 2</div>
      <div class="bottom">other content of form 2</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed!

Comment: Glad to help, just make sure you keep this in a container positioned relative so the absolute element stays contained.

Comment: So I have to make now div `#container` relative?

Answer (score 0):

If You need content to bottom u have to add another `<div>` in bottom section.

```css
 #form1 {
    width: 68%;
    padding-left: 32%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: aliceblue;
}
#form2 {
    position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <form id="form1">
    <!-- Content of Form1 -->
    </form> 
    <form id="form2">
    <!-- Content of Form2 -->
    </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `float: left;` for `#form1`
https://jsfiddle.net/xixe/g74p7f2v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need a container for both and form1 float:left, second will wrap naturally:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</div>
<div class="right">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">

<label><input type="text"></label> 
<label><input type="text"></label> 
<label><input type="text"></label> 
<label><input type="text"></label> 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
 float:left; 
 width:300px; 
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.right {
 border:1px solid blue;
}

input {
display: block;
 margin: 20px;
}
```

[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nmrrddf/)